# Java - playing the same sound multiple times at once

Tags: audio

I'm developing a game and I'm having some issues playing the same sound multiple times, as in if you activate one sound that is already playing it shouldn't cancel the first one. The solution I found here on Stackoverflow was to read it into a byte array which I did the following way:

```
public SoundObject(AudioInputStream audioIn) {

    try {
        af = audioIn.getFormat();
        size = (int) (af.getFrameSize() * audioIn.getFrameLength());
        audio = new byte[size];
        info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, af, size);
        audioIn.read(audio, 0, size);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void playSound() {
    try {
        Clip localSound = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        localSound.open(af, audio, 0, size);
        localSound.start();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This worked perfectly up until now that I tried to export it in a jar file, the jar file for some reason has issues playing a byte array which leads to the sounds cutting off after just a few milliseconds, I managed to find one post with the same issue where someone suggested the following solution:

```
    public SoundObject(String filePath) {
    try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Loader.class.getResource(filePath));
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Play the sound in a separate thread.
public void playSound() {
    Runnable soundPlayer = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                clip.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
                clip.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(soundPlayer).start();
}
```

Using the second method worked for jar files but the issue then is instead that the sound does not play as good as it did before, I have a shoot function and if you shoot very fast this method doesn't always pick up that and sometimes fails to play a sound when I press space to shoot. So with these 2 solutions I have to choose from either having unreliable sound that doesn't always play or I won't be able to export it to a runnable JAR.

Does anyone have any experience with these kind of issues?

edit: Here's a clip to show you how the 2 jars work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZPOIhHZSJM&

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is trying the TinySound library. It is free code, available on github. This code provides a minimal mixer, and Clips can be played concurrently.

I am having a hard time figuring out what might be going wrong with your code. I also made a mixer that I use in games, and it supports concurrent playbacks for Clips. I store the sounds as floats between -1 to 1. Each play instance takes a cursor from a pre-made pool (which limits the number of concurrent playbacks) that tracks the position in the float array, and is consulted and incremented in the while loop where the various sounds are added together (simple addition) and converted to bytes that are output via a SourceDataLine. That's the basic plan, if you decide to go that route.

You might get some more efficiency in your second setup by making a thread pool, and having your sounds as close as possible to ready to play upon being called. With a mixer, you only need one thread for the audio.

Is there any sort of error in the first example? I don't see, from the code given, why sounds would get cut off due to the use of a jar. Is something cutting them off, such as another sound, or an ending of the calling thread?

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I don't quite understand how your mixer works, sound is what I'm having most issues with and both these solution were find online and I simply modified them to work in my program.

do you have any idea on how to set up a thread pool for my example?

And lastly I don't think there's any issue in my first example, it worked very well until I decided to create a jar file now and share it around. I really don't understand why it would cut off when using it in a jar since it still plays through a clip.

Comment: I recored a clip to show you the difference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZPOIhHZSJM&
The first one is with the byte array and the second one with the thread method, as you can hear when I'm holding in the shoot button it doesn't sound like it sound. When I use the byte array in eclipse it sounds flawless.

Comment: Neat! I can't tell who the head is. Anyone in particular? i learned about thread pools from "Java Concurrency in Practice" by Goetz. Good book, but a difficult read for those of us with only a few year's experience. I bet there is a Java Tutorials section, or a tutorial site that can help on the topic of Executor Services or Thread Pools. For debugging the Eclipse/Jar issue, try some println's and include them with the jar: e.g., verify the size of the sound files after loading, and also in the block with the start() command. You can take them out after problem is found.

Comment: I added the following to the playsound part after it has loaded and before it's started:

System.out.println(localSound.getFrameLength());


they print the same size of the framelength both when playing through the jar and through eclipse which makes me even more confused :/ Is there any other size I could test out or what else could be the problem?

The head is actually the king of Sweden haha, me and my friends has gotten a habit of using that sprite as a placeholder for our projects before we get a proper sprite.

Comment: I would basically try to verify all assumptions, for example, that all of the variables (size, audio, af) are identical in the two contexts. Maybe (long shot) Eclipse is loading a different audio file than the one being used in the Jar? (are data dumps identical?) "Trouble shoot" by making the simplest possible program that shows this error. That might be some code that is just the playback of a single explosion, one in Eclipse, then as a jar. It's mysterious, to say the least! And maybe reconsider using TinySound. There are some good posts about it on java-gaming.org.